# Can't set a bootstrap column to display none

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two columns which should be 9 spaces and 3 spaces at col-sm and above. At any width below that, I need first column to take up all 12 spaces, and I want the other column to not even display and take up no space anywhere. Should be easy but I can't seem to figure out how to do it reading bootstrap docs. I've tried a number of different col settings and none of them work and the 3 space column always displays wrapped underneath the 9 space column and still only takes up 3 spaces. Here's the last unsuccessful try. There's some sort of subtlety that I am missing

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-9">
        </div>
        <div class="d-col-none d-sm-block col-sm-3">          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the [Bootstrap Display Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) and you will see that `d-col...` isn't existing.

You should write`d-none` or `d-xl-none`:

> As such, the classes are named using the format:
>
> `.d-{value}` for xs
>
> `.d-{breakpoint}-{value}` for sm, md, lg, and xl.

Comment: I've been reading the documentation and since I knew that "col" meant anything under sm (xs), I mistakenly added it to the display property. Thanks

Comment: `col` say `column` but NOT under sm. When you write `col` the system understand `col-{default-breakpoint}` who is alway the minimum (`xs`). So `d` and `col` (and others) works the same way with breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `col-xs-12` to the first column and `hidden-xs` on the second column.

Comment: Is didn't found any documentation for `hidden-{breakpoint}` on boostrap